# Uncaught TypeError: btnSubmit is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to store some user information in firebase cloud store.
The problem is I created a form to enforce the user to fill all the fields and to make the email property works well. when I put them in a form I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: btnSubmit is not a function
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

when I remove the form tag it works well, but the user can submit the form without filling it, which is not good.
This is my code:

```js
//firestore code
  var db = firebase.firestore();
    function btnSubmit(){
  
    var inputText = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
 
    // Add a new document in collection
    db.collection("users").doc().set({
      
        name: inputText,
        email: email
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> exam.</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
              <div class="form-container-in">
      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="left-divider"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="form-group">

           <h2 >your Information </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <form>
  <label for="fname"><b>  name </b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name  " name="fname" id="fname" required>

  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="email"><b> email</b></label>
   <input type="email" placeholder="email " name="email" id="email" required><br>
   
     <button onclick="btnSubmit()" id="btnSubmit">go </button>

   <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

 <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

 <script>
   // Your web app's Firebase configuration
   // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
   var firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "---",
     authDomain: "--",
     databaseURL: "---",
     projectId: "--",
     storageBucket: "--",
     messagingSenderId: "--",
     appId: "--",
     measurementId: "--"
   };
   // Initialize Firebase
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   firebase.analytics();
 </script>
     <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many reasons **not** to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers: Those kinds of handlers can only call **global** functions. Apparently, your `btnSubmit` isn't a global. (It would be if the code you've shown for it appeared at the top level of a non-module `script`, as it appears to in your question, but presumably the code in the question is an excerpt from a larger function, and not at the top-level scope of it.)

The normal error you'd get for this would be a `ReferenceError` because trying to read the value of an undeclared identifier causes that kind of error. The reason you're not getting that is you have `id="btnSubmit"` on your `button` element, which creates an automatic global with that name that refers to the button.

Instead, hook up your handler with modern event handling:

```
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Your handler code here
});
```

You can still declare the function separately if you want to, without it being a global. If you do that, hook it up from code in a scope where your `btnSubmit` function exists (for instance, just after it), like this:

```
function btnSubmit() {
    // Your handler code here
}
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", btnSubmit);
```

Comment: Thanks ! this works with me , but it still has the problem of the required fields, when the user clicks the submit button without filling all the fields, the information is stored in the firestore .